# meaning of the phrasal verb "get up" in context

Tags: meaning-in-context

It is from this [video](https://youtu.be/FmeJeom0SN8). It is at around 3 minute and 16 second. The context is a coach shows how to do exercises.

> Do it in the one-and-a-half style to reinforce that you have got it up there with the muscle itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**get (something) up** is transitive and synonymous with **raise** or **lift**.

Do it in the X style to reinforce that you have brought it to that height using the muscle itself.

The tenses of the original utterance are rather a mish-mash: **to reinforce that you have got it up there**.

The recommended approach, if carried out properly, will exercise the muscle in question.